# Control when IPython/Jupyter switches to exponential notation for floating point numbers

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Sometimes the result of some calculation in IPython is some hard to read floating point number like `436132624031153.8`. I absolutely don't mind the 16 significant digits, my problem is that its very hard to see the order of magnitude of this number in one glance you need to count the number digits before the decimal point.

I would prefer if IPython would switch to exponent notation for numbers larger than, let's say 10^7, but without showing fewer significant digits (like this: `4.361326240311538e14`. Alternatively something like grouping leading digits into groups of 3 with something like spaces (like this: `436 132 624 031 153.8`) could help too.

Is there any way to achieve this in IPython (7.3) / Jupyter notebooks?

I know about IPython's `%format` which lets you specify an old-style `%`-format string for formatting floating point output, but as far as I can see none of the possibilities does what I want.